# Trouble aligning text in a JLabel centrally within a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I'm fairly new to Java and programming in general and I've run into a problem that I can't seem to solve. In my program I have two JPanels, containing a JLabel and three JButtons respectively, and the panels are arranged in a GridLayout within the frame.

My problem is that I can't get the text in the JLabel to sit centrally to the north of the first JPanel. Originally I was using a FlowLayout that arranged it in the orientation I wanted, but when the contained String became longer than a certain length, it just went off-screen. With the current setup, the text wraps appropriately, but always starts off aligned to the left.

[Example screenshot of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzBRr.jpg)

I've searched around the site and looked at multiple answers - indeed I thought my issue would be solved by using HTML (This does solve the wrapping issue and aligns the second line centrally, as seen below) - but I still can't figure out how to align the first line centrally.

[Example using longer String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Iln.jpg)

Here's my current code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class UITests extends JFrame {

    private JLabel txtWindow = new JLabel();
    private JButton jb1 = new JButton();
    private JButton jb2 = new JButton();
    private JButton jb3 = new JButton();
    private final Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    public UITests() {

        //Creating the top panel for the JLabel
        JPanel panelA = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        txtWindow.setForeground(Color.white);
        txtWindow.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        txtWindow.setText("<html><div style='text-align: center;'>" + "Mellon"
                + "</div></html>");
        panelA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelA.add(txtWindow, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        //Creating the bottom panel for the JButtons
        JPanel panelB = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));

        //setting up button properties
        jb1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jb2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        jb1.setForeground(Color.white);
        jb2.setForeground(Color.white);
        jb3.setForeground(Color.white);

        jb1.setFocusPainted(false); //Stopping highlighting of button
        jb2.setFocusPainted(false);
        jb3.setFocusPainted(false);

        jb1.setFont(font);
        jb2.setFont(font);
        jb3.setFont(font);


        panelB.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelB.add(jb1);
        panelB.add(jb2);
        panelB.add(jb3);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
        add(panelA);
        add(panelB);

        setTitle("Screen");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UITests();
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, and apologies if there exists a very similar question; I did my best to find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `txtWindow.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);`, like so:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JLabel txtWindow = new JLabel();
    private JButton jb1 = new JButton();
    private JButton jb2 = new JButton();
    private JButton jb3 = new JButton();
    private final Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    public Main() {

        //Creating the top panel for the JLabel
        JPanel panelA = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        txtWindow.setForeground(Color.white);
        txtWindow.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        txtWindow.setText("Mellon");
        txtWindow.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panelA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelA.add(txtWindow, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        //Creating the bottom panel for the JButtons
        JPanel panelB = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));

        //setting up button properties
        jb1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jb2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        jb1.setForeground(Color.white);
        jb2.setForeground(Color.white);
        jb3.setForeground(Color.white);

        jb1.setFocusPainted(false); //Stopping highlighting of button
        jb2.setFocusPainted(false);
        jb3.setFocusPainted(false);

        jb1.setFont(font);
        jb2.setFont(font);
        jb3.setFont(font);


        panelB.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelB.add(jb1);
        panelB.add(jb2);
        panelB.add(jb3);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
        add(panelA);
        add(panelB);

        setTitle("Screen");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

This will center the text in the label.
Then you won't need to add HTML, so you can also `setText("Melon");` directly, instead of using HTML.

### Edit 1

For both short and long strings though try combining your centered HTML div tag and the `setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);` call, like so:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JLabel txtWindow = new JLabel();
    private JButton jb1 = new JButton();
    private JButton jb2 = new JButton();
    private JButton jb3 = new JButton();
    private final Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    public Main() {

        //Creating the top panel for the JLabel
        JPanel panelA = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        txtWindow.setForeground(Color.white);
        txtWindow.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        final String text = "Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon Mellon";
        txtWindow.setText("<html><div style='text-align: center;'>" + text + "</div></html>");
        txtWindow.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panelA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelA.add(txtWindow, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        //Creating the bottom panel for the JButtons
        JPanel panelB = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));

        //setting up button properties
        jb1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jb2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        jb1.setForeground(Color.white);
        jb2.setForeground(Color.white);
        jb3.setForeground(Color.white);

        jb1.setFocusPainted(false); //Stopping highlighting of button
        jb2.setFocusPainted(false);
        jb3.setFocusPainted(false);

        jb1.setFont(font);
        jb2.setFont(font);
        jb3.setFont(font);


        panelB.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelB.add(jb1);
        panelB.add(jb2);
        panelB.add(jb3);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
        add(panelA);
        add(panelB);

        setTitle("Screen");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried this and it works for short Strings, but when they reach a length longer than the width of the UI window they just go off screen with a '. . .' Adding <html></html> tags causes the text to wrap properly, so longer Strings appear on-screen in their entirety, however the first line will be centrally aligned, but the second aligns left - essentially the inverse of the problem I was having initially.

Comment: @JamesHearn I edited my answer. Tested with both setHorizontalAlignment and your centered HTML div tag, and it works for both short and long strings.